# Installing PYMC on Win64 - but MinGW does not seem to compile

Tags: python, windows, pymc

I'm trying to install PYMC on a Win7-64 machine, using Python 2.7.3, installed as part of Python(x, y).

I've attempted to use `python setup.py install`, but that didn't work. I then went down the route of installing MinGW and MSYS as per these instructions http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/INSTALL.html, but I still have the error message below. I have added the details to my path.

I have also tried using the MCMC linked to via https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/pymc/install$20windows/pymc/_10AZdgd620/wFPh4qium8QJ and the additional compiler details listed here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pymc/1-ENfS5NBQE and here http://ultrainfinitum.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/python-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsallbat.html, which state to use the following compiler commands, `setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32` or `python setup.py build --force -c mingw32`, then `python setup.py install --force --skip-build`.

The error message I'm getting is as follows:

```
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
   func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 284, in _exit_function
    info('process shutting down')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 284, in _exit_function
    info('process shutting down')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Any ideas on what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

## Quick Solution (with Visual Studio Express)

Install [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/VC/). This will give you all the `vcvarsall.*` dependencies.

## Using MinGW

Make sure to select the C, C++ and other dev tools to ensure you get `make.exe`.

After this, set your `PATH` to include MinGW32's bin directory as well as `msys\1.0\bin`

Edit the distutils.cfg file located at `C:\Python26\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg` to set your compiler options.

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```

Comment: So now a different error message on the compile step, going down the MiniGW route:

Comment: I tried the above, but with no joy -- I've put progress [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878430/installing-pymc-then-matplotlib-win7-64-continues-to-fail-despite-workarounds) to canvas wider opinion on how to proceed, as both steps you suggest fail.

Comment: That's really too bad. What happens when you run `gcc --version` at the command line?